# Java - Socket Programming - How can I make a client receive msg from multiple servers?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I need to have multiple client talk to multiple servers and process responses from them.

So far, I have been able to write the server code which binds to multiple clients (spawns a thread for each client) and client connect to multiple servers.

The place where I facing problem is on the client side - I am not able to receive responses from the servers.

The sequence of operations are as below -

Suppose I have 2 servers and 1 client. client connects to both servers, sends them messages, both servers receive it and both send a reply to the client - I am not able to receive this reply.

Server Code -

```
 @Override
  public void run() {
    try {

      // create a serversocket to listen to requests
      ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

      // create n sockets to listen to 5 client
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        // create a processor thread for each to read and process the incoming Messages
        Processor processor = new Processor(socket);
        processor.start();
      }

     serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Processor at server code -

```
@Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
      OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

      while (true) {
        String str = in.readObject();

        System.out.println(message);

        out.write("Got your message " + message.toString());

      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Processor completed " );
  }
```

Client code -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    // make the connections with other nodes
    connections = connect();

    // connect() creates connections from the client to all servers and stores the socket and out objects in the object called Connections.Code omitted to avoid clutter

    // process all the commands 
    while(!commands.isEmpty()){

      for(int i=0 ; i<2; i++){
      send(commands.poll() , i);

    }

      Thread.sleep(500);
    }

  }


  // Sends Message m to the node i
  public static synchronized void send(Message m, int i) {
    try {
      connections.outs[i].writeInt(m.nodeId);
      connections.outs[i].writeInt(m.timestamp);
      connections.outs[i].writeObject(m.type);
      connections.outs[i].writeObject(m.value);
      connections.outs[i].flush();

      InputStreamReader isr = new       InputStreamReader(connections.sockets[i].getInputStream());
      final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

      new Thread() {
        public void run() {
          try {
            while (true) {
              String message = br.readLine();
              System.out.println("Message received from the server : " +message);
            }
          } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }.start();

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

I am sure I am doing something wrong when listening to the message. Any suggestion no how to receive and process messages from multiple servers would be very helpful.

TIA

Comment: "A client listen" ?

Comment: Describe what happens when you run it. Error messages? Hangs? Have your tried a debugger?

Comment: @slim I disagree to the close-vote and the comment. Maddie describs a concrete problem that can be compiled and debugged by members of this network. Please be carefull in using the word nonsense, a unused variable is no nonsense.

Comment: @PeterRader it won't compile unless you put a lot of guesswork into defining variables that are currently undeclared. And the failure is not described.

Comment: @slim Ah, i see: `connections.out`

Comment: n, message, commands. And, not a variable, but what goes on in `connect()`

Comment: @slim Ok I agree partial with close-vote because a range of members of this network may not be able to debug.

Comment: @slim I removed a lot of code logic which was not relevant my question, will take care to retain variable declaration going forward. I have not taken some code and edited it to suit my usecase. I am new to threads and socket programming - may be that's why the code is not upto the mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing two problems:

## 1. You did not flush.

> out.write("Got your message " + message.toString());

## 2. In the server you send no \n

The problem is the method `readLine`

```
  new Thread() {
    public void run() {
      try {
        while (true) {
          String message = br.readLine();
          System.out.println("Message received from the server : " +message);
        }
      } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }.start();
```

from [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()):

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

But the Server neither send a \n nor a \r. Try

```
  out.write("Got your message " + message.toString() + "\n");
```

Comment: Thank you @Peter Rader I will try what you suggested.

Comment: Adding a new line and flush helped. I am creating a new thread for every new message from the server - Is there a way to reduce those number of threads? Also, at what point should I destroy these threads?

Comment: @maddie A thread may the most special kind of object having a special state beside instantication.  A Thread can be running, so what do you mean. The count of instances of a thread or the count of running threads?

Comment: I guess I was not clear. In the send(msg,i) method, I am creating a new Thread  `new Thread() {
        public void run() {
          try {
            while (true) {
              String message = br.readLine();
              System.out.println("Message received from the server : " +message);
            }
          } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }.start();` This is creating one thread per message I receive from the server. Is there a better way to handle this? How can I create just one thread per server instead?

Comment: @maddie This is a good question, but I am not experienced enougth to answer that question. Post your question at codereview might help.

Comment: Sure. Thank you.